# Magento 2: how to display notification after module install via zip/composer?

Tags: admin, magento2.3, backend, composer, notification

I want to display a backend admin notification

**Example:Your module Test_Product installed successfully!**

In the yellow bar after my custom module Test_Product will be installed successfully in Magento instance via zip/composer.

So how can I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

This is the responsible class: **Magento\Framework\Notification\MessageList**

You can check this tutorial for a complete example: https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/add-custom-admin-system-message/